# Trace Dependents does not work in Excel Tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have this formula:

```
=MAX(myTable[lookupID])
```

The table `myTable` is in another sheet.
I select a cell in column `lookupID`. Then, when I click **Formulas** > **Trace Dependents**, I get this:

[image: Trace dependents]

How to make Trace Dependents work for tables?

Comment: It's seems to be a bug, not a feature, and I don't think you could fix it. Workaround can be to save your file with a different name and convert the table to range, then tracing dependents will work.

Comment: Using Tables and Max - I got dependent tracing to work just fine in Excel 365.